# What prevents third-party access and “mining” when serving data to a front-end via REST API?

Tags: api, rest

Just as a context, I'm not a web developer or anything, but I occasionally try small projects mostly for fun, so I might misuse some terms.

Recently I understood that there exists two patterns for making data available in a page:

- Have the server access the database, then rendering a template based on the data and "delivering" a ready page for the user.
- Send an "incomplete" page, and let the front-end fill in the data with scripts.

In the second pattern, I would rely on an API as a bridge between my front-end and my database and basically my front-end would make calls to endpoints `/api/something` which returns json objects that are used to fill the page.

Although this seems like the most common pattern, it raises a red flag for me because: What prevents people from accessing my API from third-party applications and obtain my data in a nice structured way? For example, if Stack Overflow would load questions in the front-end through an API call, that API has to be open and the code is available at the front-end. What would prevent someone to create a "clone" of Stack Overflow using its data or just constantly call the API for data mining?

I understand that data can be simply scraped when the page is completely rendered by the backend, but that still seem less problematic than openly providing data in a nice structured json object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally the advice I give people is to accept that people *may* steal your content. There are ways to make this harder to do, but ultimately your business shouldn't hinge on this *not* happening.

The most obvious ways to mitigate this problem is doing this like bot detection (excessive requests from single ip's/ip blocks) and placing things behind authentication.

If authentication is enabled, you could rate limit per user and prevent automated signups with Captchas.

> What would prevent someone to create a "clone" of Stack Overflow using its data or just constantly call the API for data mining?

People are actively scraping SO and create websites with stolen content. The value of stackoverflow goes beyond just the content though. Stackoverflow.com is where the people are and there's no reason for people to use these other sites.

Comment: There are many junk google matches for site-ripped SO questions and answers.. thankfully search engines still usually rank the original source higher, although that’s also subject to SEO shenanigans  :-/